# Forum script (or plugin) with registration throw social networks (facebook, google and vkontakte)

Tags: facebook, forum, google-plus, vk

I wish to upload forum to my website.
I had some experience with phpBB in past.
I do not like registration forms.
I wish to give option for people to register with their social network profiles.

I searched for phpBB plugin and have found few in development stage with very critical comments.

I am interested in facebook, google and vkontakte networks.

Could you recommend such forum script or plugin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found forum with required features out of box but VanillaForums has OpenID, Facebook, Google and Vkontakte plugins

Previous I used phpBB but I have not found all required plugins that work.
The best solution for phpBB is loginza and similar services but I like to work without 3rd party services.